Some email being bounced after change of nameservers
I now know that I should not have moved nameservers without having disabled DNSSEC first, but I have. Not only that, I have also moved them to a DNS host that doesn't support DNSSEC (digital ocean).
Is my best option, at this stage to simply change the nameservers back to the original? Will this fix my issue or cause further problems?
The reason for making the change is that my email is hosted using mailinabox on a digital ocean droplet and the IP range has been blacklisted. This is affecting my ability to send emails to Hotmail addresses.
All I really want to do is to move my email to Google. Could I achieve this by changing the MX records on mailinabox and then, disabling DNSSEC and changing the nameserver?

As you said that the IP range has been blacklisted, even if DNS records can be resolved correctly, emails may be bounced or moved to spam/junk box. Please try to:

delist IP address using to send email from blacklist
using relay email service (recommended)

About nameserver, it only plays the role of resolving records. You can use the old nameserver. In case that you want to use the new one, please delete the old DNSSEC record. If not doing so, DNSSEC will prevent records from being resolved properly.
Finally, you can rely on the messages in the returned email when your emails got bounced to know the reasons.
